# How do I fix indentation error when creating a class in Python?

Tags: python, class, syntax-error

Every time I try to create a class, it gives me the `IndentationError` when I haven't even added indentations yet.

[image: Error Screenshot]

I have tried restarting Jupyter and my PC and there is no luck. I have also tried using another notebook but still face the error.

Comment: When you define a class in python, you need to add at least one statement which will serve as the body of the class.
If you don't have anything to write for now, you may write `pass` (with indentation).
That's why it says `EXPECTED an indented block`.

Comment: _when I haven't even added indentations yet_ Yes, that's the error.  There SHOULD BE indentations, and there aren't.

Comment: There are some useful reasoning skills to learn here. `IndentationError` means something is wrong about the indentation. It **does not** mean that there was an indent that was wrong. It could also mean that there *wasn't* an indent and there *should have been*. Which is why the error message says "*Expected* indent". If an error message says that something was "expected", that means it **should** be there (by definition of "expected"), but **isn't** (otherwise, it wouldn't be an error).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error shows, it is expecting an indented block after the class.

So add a statement in there, example:

```py
class Animal():
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

You should understand the basics of classes in python for this. It is working fine, the only thing is that your code is incomplete. After you declare a class, it is simply expecting a class body.